# Convert time to int

Tags: c++, boost

Как преобразовать дату/время в количество секунд чтобы хранить в `int32`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime t = boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time();
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    t += boost::posix_time::minutes(1);
    std::cout << t << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

И есть ли еще какой-то способ получить значение времени по UTC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `boost::posix_time::to_time_t(t)`
2. Можно получить в виде количества секунд используя функцию `time()` с нулевым аргументом: `auto t = time(nullptr)` (библиотека `<ctime>`). Преобразовать полученный результат в utc можно используя функцию из той же библиотеки `localtime_s()`: 1-й аргумент указатель на структуру `tm`, куда необходимо записать результат, 2-й - указатель на значение времени в секундах

---

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto t = time(nullptr);
    tm ct;
    localtime_s(&ct, &t);
    std::cout << ct.tm_year << "." << ct.tm_mon << "." << ct.tm_mday << " ";
    std::cout << ct.tm_hour << ":" << ct.tm_min << ":" << ct.tm_sec << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно. Только у меня почему-то функция называется `localtime_r()`.

Comment: @slippyk, по поводу постфикса `_r`: **POSIX** определяет потокобезопасную альтернативу функции `localtime` (`localtime_s`) - `localtime_r`, которая идентична функции `localtime_s`, за исключением того, что она не проверяет валидность входных параметров. [источник](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime) и [источник](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html)